# Working with multiple ordered async services

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I have multiple services being injected into my component. Two of these provide a list of objects that are needed to look up items for my third service. My issue is the async calls to them are not always in order. Nesting the calls inside each other doesn't seem to work in every case and it wouldn't make since to nest them anyways. How can I force my services to load all their values so I can use them? I tried putting my services and loading their responses in my constructor and then trying to call those responses in ngOnInit(), but that did not work either.

Typescript

```
 constructor(     
    private stateService: StatesService, 
    private zoneService: ZoneDetailService, 
    private countyService: CountyService) { 

      //gather states from service
      this.stateService.GetStates().subscribe(response => {
        this.statesResults = response;
        //do something with response
       });

      //gather counties from service
      this.countyService.GetCounties().subscribe(response => {
        this.countyResults = response;       

          //gather detail from service
          this.zoneService.GetZoneDetails(this.prodPointId).subscribe(response => { 

            this.state = response.stateCode;                
            this.apiCountyCode = response.apiCountyCode;              

            //return single record
            let answer = this.countyResults.filter(c => c.countyCode === response.apiCountyCode).map(c => {
              return c.id;
            });

            let answer2 = this.statesResults.filter(c => c.stateCode === response.stateCode).map(c => {
              return c.id;
            });
```

As shown the stateService does not load the stateResults so it is left as 'undefined' and then the filter does not work. I need to ensure both my stateService and countyService are run before my detailService. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can execute all observables at the same time and wait for the result with `Observable.forkJoin()`
Let me show you an example:

```
const queries: Observable<any>[] = [];

queries.push(this.countyService.GetCounties());
queries.push(this.stateService.GetStates());          
queries.push(this.zoneService.GetZoneDetails(this.prodPointId));

Observable.forkJoin(queries)
  .take(1)
  .subscribe(data => { 
     this.countyResults = data[0]
     this.statesResults = data[1]
     this.zoneDetails = data[2]
  }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. I had to rearrange a few things, but will this forkJoin I was able to achieve what I wanted. I need to read up more on the rxjs.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways you can do this, but a [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) would work here.  ForkJoin takes an array of observables and completes when they have all finished.  So:

```
import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
forkJoin([this.statesService.getStates(), this.countyService.getCounties(), this.zoneService.GetZoneDetails(this.prodPointId)])
    .subscribe(res => {
        // res[0] would be the result of getStates
        // res[1] would be the result of getCounties
})
```

I will caution you though, I have found that subscribing to observables in services is usually a bad code smell.  I typically try to only subscribe to observables inside components and do all of my logic in rxjs functions in the service.

Comment: Completely understand. I was not doing manipulation at the service level. I was in the component.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood, thought it was in a service.  Good luck!